# How to handle downloading .xlsx file in firefox using webdriver where window popup is defaulted to 'Open with' radio button instead of 'Save file'

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow, savefiledialog

I have a web application which has a link. When clicked on this link, it opens window popup asking to open file with particular application.

I have written following code for creating firefox profile which works fine for other file extensions, but not for .xlsx file.

```
        profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);

        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\Download");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\Download");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\Download");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xls, application/zip,text/csv,application/msword,application/excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/pdf," +
                "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword,application/unknown,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Below is the popup i am getting:-
[image: window popup]

- I think, since window popup is not defaulted to 'Save File' radio button, firefox profile is not working. Any solution to handle this scenario?

Comment: In code, specified as "application/xls," is it ok? as here using .xlsx..

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer, ya application/xls is working fine for files having .xls extension and when radio button is defaulted to 'Save File' on window popup.

Comment: Fine, did you tried application/xlsx? as you are using xlsx file here..may i know what happen when you did like this?

Comment: Yes, i used application/xlsx, but it didn't worked. I think main issue is popup is defaulted to 'Open With' radio button. Had it been 'Save File', my code might have worked.

Comment: Hoo.. I will also try this..  Meanwhile we can use keys simulation may be tab and enter to do this.. And also can't we save settings to save to default in profile and invoke that profile here?

Comment: Ya.. I need to know same thing as how we can set popup ti Save File option :)

Comment: try this in profile..and call that..i hope it works. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_adding-download-actions

Answer (score 5):

This Preference worked for me.

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

The following table documents the HTTP MIME types that are available when working with Office 2007 documents:

**Ext   MIME Type**

- .doc   application/msword
- .dot   application/msword
- .docx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- .dotx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
- .docm  application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
- .dotm  application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
- .xls   application/vnd.ms-excel
- .xlt   application/vnd.ms-excel
- .xla   application/vnd.ms-excel
- .xlsx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- .xltx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
- .xlsm  application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
- .xltm  application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
- .xlam  application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
- .xlsb  application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
- .ppt   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
- .pot   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
- .pps   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
- .ppa   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
- .pptx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
- .potx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
- .ppsx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
- .ppam  application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
- .pptm  application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
- .potm  application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
- .ppsm  application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12